# Plagiarism in a taught course

Tags: united-kingdom

I am a Phd student. I've been cited for plagiarism on my taught course. Will this appear on my transcript? And will this have implications for securing a teaching career after my PhD?

Comment: You don't even disclose your country. How should we know the regulations of your university? Why don't you ask there?

Comment: @user111388, the UK tag is present, actually.

Comment: What do you mean "cited for plagiarism on my taught course"? Do you mean you were taking a taught module at the same time as completing a PhD?

Comment: @Buffy: Ah okay, didn't see that. But I still believe it should be mentioned in the question - I don't see the question making sense otherwise.

Comment: @Michael Nkrumah  I am not able to understand the phrase "my taught course" so please edit it a bit.  Are you the instructor, the person who designed the course, a student in the course?